# How to implement TCP data transmition or Serial Port comunication to asp.net web app

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications

I am trying to do some project with some serial port or TCP comunication. I also want to have acess to MySql databese. I have 2 main questions:

**1.** It's even possible to use serial port from browser?

**2.** Which project type should I use? I wanted to choose blazor-server side but as I noticed I can't use there TCP comunication or serial port.

Comment: 1. No, not directly. Browser would have to connect to a server and the server would have to make the serial connection (which means the device must be connected to the server, not the local machine - I'm guessing that's not really what you need). Or you have to build a browser plug-in which may be able to do it, but check documentation etc for the browser about what device access is available etc.

Comment: 2. To be honest this sounds more like a job for a desktop application - it may of course still connect to a Web API as a backend, to allow storage of data in a centralised database, and shared implementation of business logic, security etc through the API (depending on your exact requirements).

Comment: The following may be helpful: https://www.moxa.com/en/products/industrial-edge-connectivity/serial-device-servers